# Fastest way to load data in Go

Tags: go

I need to regularly load over `300'000 rows x 78 columns` of data into my Go program.

**Currently I use (`import github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize`):**

```
xlsx, err := excelize.OpenFile("/media/test snaps.xlsm")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

//read all rows into df
df := xlsx.GetRows("data")
```

It takes about *4* minutes on a decent PC using Samsung 960 EVO Series - M.2 Internal SSD.

Is there a faster way to load this data? Currently it takes me more time to read the data than processing it. I'm also opened to other file formats.

Comment: As a first step, try switching to [`File.Rows`](https://godoc.org/github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize#File.Rows).

Comment: "Is there a faster way to load this data ?" Maybe? Have you looked at alternative libraries? Have you profiled the program to see where time is being spent? If most of the time is in reading the file from disk then likely the only way to make it faster is to use a faster disk.

Comment: If you're going to load more than 10 million cells regularly, you should really consider **not** using xls format to store your data. For the sake of common sense, do convert your data into some format close to your memory representation. And if I/O read is the bottleneck, compress your data to reduce the data needed to be read.

Comment: Assuming your data are all float32s this is about 45 MB of data. With the right data structure this should take < 1 second to load on your machine. I agree with icza that you should store your data in a different file format and maybe import it once from .xls, convert it to your own format and when you are done (we do not know what exactly it is that you do with the data) you can still export it back to .xls.

Comment: thanks Icza and @gonutz, do you have any other file format to suggest ? I don't need to export it back to .xls, I output charts.

Comment: thanks @TimCooper, I will try file.rows and revert

Comment: If it is really just all numbers of the same type, then just write the width and height as two integers, then in one go write all the data back-to-back, either row-wise or column-wise, what you prefer. That is the simplest format I can imagine and it will be fast.

Comment: If performance is critical, consider using a custom binary format, and for implementation consider using [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) and [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/). You can easily wrap such implementation in a compressed stream too.

Comment: Check to see if you really need the whole thing in memory.  If you know that you are only summing columns in a row for instance, you don't need to hold more than one row in memory at any given time.  In other words, send the data through counters.  If you can stream data like this, then you may find order-of-magnitude speed ups.  

Putting the whole data structure is sometimes necessary, but only if the order in which you traverse it forces you to do so.  Note that uploading raw files should be at least 50MB/s in throughput.

Comment: thanks @Rob, I really need all rows and most columns in memory. But all good in terms of performance, it's much faster that way than before.

Comment: Tim's suggestion to use File.Rows appears to not just blindly pull the whole thing into memory.  If you have an iterator with a Next(), it's unknown how much data it had to pull into memory (a good thing): "func (rows *Rows) Next() bool".  If it returned "[]Row", then it has to have it in memory.  I would add to gonutz advice: stored as array of rows (with columns for that row next to each other) is best for write, and stored as array of columns (with rows for that column next to each other) is best for read (when doing stats over whole columns etc). I would hope excel lib does it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, instead of using the XLS format, use a custom, fast data format for reading and writing your table.

In the most basic case, just write the number of columns and rows to a binary file, then write all the data in one go. This will be very fast, I have created a little example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Dqvm9LRnc0f) which just writes 300.000 by 40 float32s to a file and reads them back. On my machine this takes about 400ms and 250ms (notice that the file is hot in cache after writing it, may take longer on initial read).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "os"

    "github.com/gonutz/tic"
)

func main() {
    const (
        rowCount = 300000
        colCount = 40
    )
    values := make([]float32, rowCount*colCount)
    func() {
        defer tic.Toc()("write")
        f, _ := os.Create("file")
        defer f.Close()
        binary.Write(f, binary.LittleEndian, int64(rowCount))
        binary.Write(f, binary.LittleEndian, int64(colCount))
        check(binary.Write(f, binary.LittleEndian, values))
    }()
    func() {
        defer tic.Toc()("read")
        f, _ := os.Open("file")
        defer f.Close()
        var rows, cols int64
        binary.Read(f, binary.LittleEndian, &rows)
        binary.Read(f, binary.LittleEndian, &cols)
        vals := make([]float32, rows*cols)
        check(binary.Read(f, binary.LittleEndian, vals))
    }()
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```